# Array[String] OR String to String

Tags: javascript, arrays

I've got an API that can return either a short Array[String] or a String itself. This is being returned by Angular's $http.get. I would like to return this as a String.

Is it safe to assume that calling the `.toString()` method on either an Array or String will not give me grief?

Example via browser console:

```
"something".toString();
"something"
["something"].toString();
"something"
```

Thanks!

Comment: I think its not a problem. If the array has more strings then you will get a single string comma separated. Make sure the array size is always 1. If not, check for type, then if it is an array, pick the first element.

Comment: What happens if the array contains more than one element?

Comment: @BillF. A single string containing all the array values comma separated will be returned. _Reference:_ [`Array.prototype.toString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/toString)...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it possible API would return Array[String1, String2] or Array[] (empty array)?
I'd better write more explicit code:

```
var apiMessage = Array.isArray(message) ? message[0] : message;
```

Comment: This is pretty much what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

Safe depends on your trust to your back-end. And that's why:

```
["something", null, undefined, {}].toString() => "something,,[object Object]"
```

Comment: The devil is always in the details.

Comment: If only you develop back by your self, so you can not fool yourself :D